# How to connect dots with a line in real time using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm writting a "3x+1" simulation code using matplotlib just for fun. I'm trying to make the values appear in real time and connected by a line. But I only get the scatter dots.

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plots = []


def three(x):

    if x == 1:
        return x

    if x % 2 == 0:
        plots.append(x/2)
        return three(x/2)
    else:
        plots.append(3*x+1)
        return three(3*x+1)


num = int(input('Number: '))


plots.append(num)
three(num)


y = []
x = [x for x in range(len(plots)+1)]
x.pop(0)

for i in plots:

   plt.plot(x[plots.index(i)], i, ".-")
   plt.pause(0.05)

plt.show()
```

Comment: 1- Your lists are confusing. `x = [x for x in range(len(plots) + 1]; x.pop(0)` is exactly equivalent to `x = list(range(1, num+1))`. 2- The data you are trying to plot, `x[plots.index(i)], i` is a single point and that is why there is no line drawn.

Comment: Is there a way of plotting it all together in realtime? I've tried FuncAnimation, but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe define exactly what you want to plot and do it on a static figure. Only once you have managed to do that you should start thinking about real time and animations. It's a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this? I am thinking the render of plt.Show is occurring after all the pauses are looped. edit- sorry I see now you are asking about connecting the plots.

```
for i in plots:

    plt.plot(x[plots.index(i)], i, ".-")
    plt.pause(0.05)

    plt.show()
```

I think your marker string is wrong found [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html). Try this

```
plt.plot(x[plots.index(i)], i, "-.")
```